# How to free 2D array memory in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, heap-memory

I am trying to allocate memory for 2D Array. But when I am trying to free up the memory it throws the segmentation fault. Kindly help me to know what I am doing wrong?

```
  int **arr1 = (int **) malloc (rows * columns * sizeof (int));

  //Array Access:
  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
      *(arr1 + i * columns + j) = ++count;

  for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
      printf ("%d", *(arr1 + i * columns + j));

  for (i = 0; i < rows*columns; i++)
    free (arr1[i]);
```

Comment: If you have done __one__ `malloc`, you have do __one__ `free`. So replace the fee-loop with a single statement `free(arr1);`.

Comment: when I tried to use only "free(arr1)", I got the following error `** Error in `/home/a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000019a6010 ***                                                                                                                  
123456789Aborted (core dumped)"

Comment: However, if i use ` int *arr1 = (int *) malloc (rows * columns * sizeof (int));` instead of double pointer, Your solution works absolutely fine. Can you brief me why it have not worked with the case of double pointer?

Comment: Using `int **arr` will have the compiler interpret `*(arr1 + i * columns + j)` as working with pointers, so `i*columns` means `i*sizeof(int *)*columns` bytes, which is different from `i*sizeof(int)*columns` bytes on platforms where `sizeof(int *) != sizeof(int)`, notably 64 bit platforms.

Comment: Why don't you instead just use linear array then `free(array);` at the end of it's use? `y * width + x` to access an element over `[y][x]` is small price to pay for objectively more readable allocation, usage and deallocation than code in your question.

Comment: Do you test this on a 32 or 64 bit OS?

Comment: @alk, its a a64 machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple rule of thumb is for every `malloc` there should be a `free`. You've allocated a block of memory that `arr1` points to, so you should deallocate that *one* block of memory.

```
free(arr1);
```

You can't free a block of memory piecemeal. If you want to do that, you need to allocate each row individually, but using a single hunk of memory as a 2D array is also fine. Allocating each row is better if the size of each row is unknown. One big allocation is better if the row size is fixed.

---

In addition, `arr1` should be a single pointer, not a double pointer. Compiler warnings should have warned you about this.

```
int *arr1 = malloc (rows * columns * sizeof(int));
```

A [double pointer](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pointer_(computer_programming)#/Multiple_indirection) is a pointer to a pointer. It's not necessary to make a double pointer to pretend a pointer is a 2D matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Schwern. I was looking for this answer only. However if I use `int **arr1 = malloc (rows * columns * sizeof(int));` and after that I use `free(arr1)`, It gives me a different error `*_** Error in /home/a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000019a6010 *** 123456789Aborted (core dumped)"_*`. I am not able to understand why is that so?

Comment: @anandamu16 It should be `int *arr1 = malloc ...`, though I don't think that's causing your problem. Without seeing all your code I can't say which `free` that error is coming from. Can you create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with all the code necessary to reproduce the error [like this](https://gist.github.com/schwern/5f4b181ec177df8283176da558ea1ff6)?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are trying to allocate an array of pointers to arrays. Your code segfaults because you `free` non-allocated memory. The proper way to allocate a "2D array"  is more like this:

```
int **arr1 = malloc (rows * sizeof (int*));

for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
  arr1[r] = malloc(columns * sizeof(int));

...

for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
  free(arr1[r]);

free(arr1);
```

Comment: Yes, I know that way of allocating memory for 2d array. I was just wondering, how to free dynamic memory for the particular case I asked for.

Comment: Anyway, Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yes, perhaps you want to allocate a large 1D array and treat it as a 2D array as @Schwern suggests below.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over each row and at each iteration, you can allocate space at creation phase and free at clearing phase it by yourself. Your code have several problems, I think that may be a better approach to write in a form like:

```
int **array = (int**) malloc( row * sizeof(int*)), i = 0, j;

for( ; i < row; i++){
    *(array + i)  = (int*) malloc(col * sizeof(int));
    for( j = 0; j < col; j++){
        *(*(array + i) + j) = i * row + j;
    }
}
```

This will create the 2d array with the values in increasing order.

While freeing:

```
for(i = 0 ; i < row; i++){
    free(*(array + i));
}
free(array);
```

Comment: Probably a copy-paste error, but in your second code block, you shouldn't be iterating over `j` when freeing.

Comment: Actually, the `for(j` loop in freeing is wrong. Only iterate the `i` loop.

Comment: Thank you for comment, I was a little bit excited, because it was my first answer :D